# Getting a Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock' calling powershell script from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am running this command/Script:

```
Exec xp_cmdshell 'powershell.exe Invoke-Command -ComputerName server01.client.local -ScriptBlock 
{Get-Process myguiapp -IncludeUserName ^| Format-Table @{Expression={$_.username}}, @{Expression= 
{$_.path}}, @{Expression={(((Get-Date) - $_.StartTime).ToString().Substring(0,8))}}}, @{Expression= 
{$_.FileVersion.tostring()}}'
```

When I run it in powershell, it works fine, but when I run it in SSMS, I get this error:

```
Invoke-Command : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 
'System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock' required by 
parameter 'ScriptBlock'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:1 char:67
+ ... ScriptBlock {Get-Process myguiapp -IncludeUserName | Format-Table @{E ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

And when I run it in SSMS without the last parameter (for FileVersion), it works fine:

```
Exec xp_cmdshell 'powershell.exe Invoke-Command -ComputerName zmcrds01.zmclient.local -ScriptBlock 
{Get-Process zmfs.gui -IncludeUserName ^| Format-Table @{Expression={$_.username}}, @{Expression= 
{$_.path}}, @{Expression={(((Get-Date) - $_.StartTime).ToString().Substring(0,8))}}}'
```

I'm running on SQL Server 2014 with Powershell 5.1

How can I fix this?

Comment: You have too many `}` after `@{Expression={(((Get-Date) - $_.StartTime).ToString().Substring(0,8))}}}`. It is closing the script block prematurely.